# How to install StyleX in a new React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, css-in-js

I want to use StyleX in my new project, but I'm having some trouble trying to use it (with NextJS).

I don't understand how to configure the "next.config.js" file (creating a "babel.config.js" file creates conflicts with "next.config.js" file).

I'm stuck at the begin of a project, and from the StyleX docs I can't see a solution, maybe I'm blind or something.

Actual situation:

.babelrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["next/babel"],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@stylexjs/babel-plugin",
      {
        dev: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
        runtimeInjection: false,
        genConditionalClasses: true,
        treeshakeCompensation: true,
        unstable_moduleResolution: {
          type: "commonJS",
          rootDir: __dirname,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const stylexPlugin = require("@stylexjs/nextjs-plugin");

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

module.exports = stylexPlugin({
  rootDir: __dirname,
})(nextConfig);

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Error:

> "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom
> babel config being present.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward to set up. First, install this plugin,

```
npm install --save-dev @stylexjs/nextjs-plugin
```

Create a `.babelrc.js` file in the root directory if it does not exist and add the below configs to the file.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@stylexjs/babel-plugin',
      {
        dev: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        runtimeInjection: false,
        genConditionalClasses: true,
        treeshakeCompensation: true,
        unstable_moduleResolution: {
          type: 'commonJS',
          rootDir: __dirname,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Adjust the `next.config.js` file with the below configs.

```
const stylexPlugin = require('@stylexjs/nextjs-plugin');

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = stylexPlugin({
  rootDir: __dirname,
})(nextConfig);
```

Now, you're ready to explore `stylex`.

Comment: Thanks, but an error occur: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present. And the Next.js docs says that .babelrc should be removed.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This conflict has been resolved by `stylex`. check this out: https://github.com/facebook/stylex/tree/main/apps/nextjs-example

Comment: Saying that they solved it is a bit short - they just removed as in not using the nextjs fonts system and trying so will still give errors

Comment: Exactly, doesn't work yet. Docs and GitHub doesn't help and I'm still trying to write the first line of code.

Comment: Ok, if anyone it's still looking at this question, I found the solution. Basically, the error comes from the standard layout.tsx file, which includes the Inter font and causes the problem. I just had to remove the import.

Answer (score 0):

next/font is not supported in a project that uses Babel. Remove usage of next/font.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the font that the create-next-app installs.

In layout.tsx remove

```js
import { Inter } from next/font/google'
```

and

```js
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
```

These are typically lines 3 and 5 respectively.

Also remove the classname on body (also in layout.tsx), so change this line

```
<body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
```

to

```
<body>{children}</body>
```

StyleX has an example for Nextjs. Here are next.config.ts and .babel.rc

https://github.com/facebook/stylex/blob/main/apps/nextjs-example/next.config.js

https://github.com/facebook/stylex/blob/main/apps/nextjs-example/.babelrc.js

Once that is done then running `npm run dev` will display

```bash
> nextjs-blog@0.1.0 predev
> npm run clean


> nextjs-blog@0.1.0 clean
> rimraf .next


> nextjs-blog@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

   Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc.js" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
 ✓ Ready in 2.2s
```